# How to interpret data extracted with Latent Dirichlet allocation

Tags: lda

I'm analyzing some files extracted with LDA, I have learned some basic knowledge about LDA from here http://blog.echen.me/2011/08/22/introduction-to-latent-dirichlet-allocation/

I have three files:

topic ids (5x600)

```
 59673453648    64345309472 1.23984E+11 52934539940 1.06263E+14
 1.05643+14     1.44524E+11 1.09535E+14 1.06368E+14 62248718804
 1.12535E+14    1.13771E+14 1.70701E+14 1.86305E+14 1.9114E+14


  Topic names (5x600)
  TBBT            The_Mummy    Spider-Man  Inception           Shrek
  Outfitters      Cheerleading  Chanel     Victoria's Secret   LV 
  Pia Mia         Ciara         Usher      Jay-z               Akon


data.df  (600X1100000)

 id 
 1  0.000111111  0.000111111 0.000111111 0.000111111 0.000111111
 2  9.883309999  9.883309999 9.883309999 9.883309999 9.883309999
 3  6.772454300  6.772454300 6.772454300 6.772454300 6.772454300
```

I assume topic ids are matched with topic names, but how to interpret the score in data.df (600 cols)?

Comment: This question is better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I also posted on Cross Validated